# SlickNav menu, each li with specific color background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slicknav

I prepare my mobile menu with `SlickNav` but I have a little problem. I can not specify my css attributes on my `<li>` beacause `SlickNav` not taken into account. The problem is that I simply want to change the background of each of my `<li>`

Any idea?

```
<ul id="menu2">
<li>Parent 1
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li>Parent 3
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 10</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
<li>non-link item</li>
<li>Parent 2
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 7</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use CSS3 :nth-child() Selector, like this:

```
ul:nth-child(1) { // first li
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
ul:nth-child(2) { // second li
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thank kitz for this solution but it seems to me that it is poorly supported in ios8, I'll try anyway

Comment: Welcome! Also, you can assign a class to each li, and apply background-color changes in each class.

Comment: When Slickmenu is in action, it crushes the added classes ...
I tried your solution, the problem is that the background also apply to the sub menus :(

Comment: I did not know you have sub menus. I think you need to handle it specially. You can try like this: ul:nth-child(2) > ul { background-color: 'your_default_color' }. Assuming yout second li is a sub menu and your sub menu is an ul.